# Attributes as local variables vs instance variables in Rails Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, attributes, instance-variables, local-variables

In custom validation methods, why are the attributes passed as local variables instead of being accessible as instance variables?

I was expecting to use `@title` instead of `title` in the custom validation below, but `@title` is `nil` in the code below. `title` contains the actual data.

```
    attr_accessible :title
    validate :do_check_title

    def do_check_title
      title =~ /^Alice in/ || errors.add(:title, "Not Alice in Wonderland")
    end
```

Looking through the active_record/core.rb

```
   def initialize(attributes = nil)
     ...
     assign_attributes(attributes) if attributes
     ...
   end
```

And then in active_record/attribute_assignment.rb

```
   def _assign_attribute(k, v)
     public_send("#{k}=", v)
```

So I guess, the attributes should be available as instance variables in the validation function.

Why are they `nil`?

Comment: Your assumption that `title` is a local variable is wrong. It's actually an attribute. It's the same as doing `self.title`. I don't know exactly why you can't use `@title`. It has something to do with ActiveRecord, but I don't know the details.

Comment: also, the attributes are never accessible directly, but 'getters' and 'setters' are defined for them when they are defined as accessible. ie, whenever we assign a value (self.title='something'), the method 'title=' is called which 'sets' the value and 'self.title' 'gets' the value.

Comment: @surase.prasad - stating the obvious. my question was why is `@title == nil`, when i think it should be available due to `_assign_attribute` above

Comment: @surase.prasad, for "normal" attributes they *are* accessible, although it's better to use getters and setters. For "ActiveRecord" attributes no instance variables are set.

Comment: @Vlr - I don't see why the code above should make them available as instance variables. Again: they *are* attributes! It's not a local variable you're using in your validation function.

Comment: i understand that they're not local. my mistake :> however, `public_send` calls the setter for that attribute, and setters do just that: `@title = title`. right?

Comment: @Vlr - it calls the setter, but that doesn't automatically mean an instance variable is set. You should look at the ActiveRecord code to find out what exactly happens, but obviously no instance variable is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really matter if you access these from a validation or other instance methods. You can see what's happening from the console (pry):

```
u = User.first
show-method u.first_name=
```

This gives you something like this:

```
generated_attribute_methods.module_eval("def #{attr_name}=(new_value); write_attribute('#{attr_name}', new_value); end", __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Now if you take a look at the `write_attribute` method, you can see that it deletes attribute cache etc. and then assign to `attributes` and it's just a hash.

```
u.attributes
```

So from now on, instead of the boring `u.first_name = "foo"`, you can use this:

```
u.send :write_attribute, "first_name", "foo"
```

and it will do the same thing (3.2.10).

Comment: Ok, got it now. I thought the setter would just create an instance variable with the same name - like setters created with attr_accessor. You're right - it only adds that to a hash.

Comment: Yep. Please accept the answer if you are satisfied with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord stores the values in the `attributes` hash and not in instance variables. I generates accessor (getter/setter) methods on the fly while you access them.

Rails needs to support the livecycle of an entity, and wraps this code in the generated methods. This is needed, so that it can support ie. `dirty?` and `changed?` methods.

The next thing are associations, they are handled through proxies, so you need to call them with methods too.

Instance variables could be seen as volatile data. They are transparent to the persistance layer.